# What's the right way to install and use bower in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, npm, bower

In a meteor project, I want to pull a few frontend packages. `bower` can pull many frontend dependencies which are not yet available using `meteor add`. In many cases, when the meteor packages are available, their versions are lagging behind the official ones, sometimes too behind to consider.

Being a bit of a Meteor newb I've tried to install bower (the most recent meteor bower package I could find):

```
$ meteor add bozhao:bower
```

but then, when I run the meteor server it crashes:

```
W20160110-15:37:57.997(2)? (STDERR) /Users/igal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.7bj3ks++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
W20160110-15:37:57.998(2)? (STDERR)                         throw(ex);
W20160110-15:37:57.998(2)? (STDERR)                               ^
W20160110-15:37:57.998(2)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: window is not defined
W20160110-15:37:57.998(2)? (STDERR)     at bower_components/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.js:526:1
```

Question is: 
What's the best strategy to install bower and use it in a meteor project? An acceptable answer may show the flow for correctly installing bower, then the `leaflet` package and it's `leaflet.markercluster` extension

## Sep 27th 2016 edit

The meteor community switched to npm, thus using bower is no longer required. Simply do `npm install <package>` and `import <package>` in your client-side code, and you can start using the component!

Comment: Meteor way is to install package https://atmospherejs.com/bevanhunt/leaflet

Comment: @0x860111 Yes I'm working with the bevanhunt:leaflet package. I need Leaflet's marker clusters plugin and I couldn't find a (non-experimental) reliable meteor package which provides it. As such I thought maybe reverting to bower can remedy the situation. Do you know about a Meteor clustering plugin I can pull which is compatible with bevanhunt:leaflet?

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: As I pointed in the update, the meteor community switched to npm, thus using bower is no longer required. Simply do `npm install <package>` and `import <package>` in your client-side code, and everything works like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

`meteor search bower` turns up a few hits, which I haven't taken the time to compare in any depth. I went with [mquandalle:bower](https://atmospherejs.com/mquandalle/bower) as I found it recommended [here](https://meteorhacks.com/meteor-weekly-getting-ready-for-1-0-bower-integration/). Perusing the doc, here is what worked for me:

```
npm install -g bower                # If not already done
meteor add mquandalle:bower
echo '{ "directory": ".meteor/local/bower" }' > .bowerrc    # If you use bower install --save
```

Then create a `bower.json` file at the top of the project tree that reads like this:

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "leaflet": ">0",
    "leaflet.markercluster": ">0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Re-run your app with `meteor run` and presto, the stylesheets and JavaScript of your modules are embedded into your page without even having to edit the `<head>`.